# How do I display all authors in a citation as an exception using natbib?

Tags: bibtex, citing, natbib

Is it possible to make an exception to the "person A et al. [2016]" formatting and cite a single bibtex reference in text, but displaying all authors as "person A, person B, person C and person D [2016]"?

I use the following line in my preamble to manage citations:

`\RequirePackage[square, sort, numbers, authoryear]{natbib} % CustomBib`

I'm using the thesis template at https://github.com/kks32/phd-thesis-template. Preamble is in `./Preamble/preamble.tex`.

Comment: Please tell us which bibliography style you use. Please also tell us if you use a citation management package (if any), e.g., `apacite` or `natbib`.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example with bibliography ([MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography)), that illustrates your code. It will be much easier to solve your question when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A comment up front: If you want to create authoryear-style citation call-outs with the `natbib` package, you should under no circumstance be specifying the options `sort` and `numbers`, as they only make sense for if numeric-style citation call-outs are desired. I take it that you've copied your setup from a template you've located on GitHub. Beware the hopefully well-intentioned but ultimately counterproductive template! The Internet is full of them. Most online LaTeX templates cause more grief than they provide help...

Anyway, just load the `natbib` package with the option `authoryear` and, if you must, the option `square`. (I believe `round` is more appropriate in general.) Next, use a suitable bibliography style; in the example below, I use `plainnat`. Please observe that `apalike`, i.e., the bibliography style that's specified by your template, is *not suitable* for your purposes. (Another reason for being extra super cautious, and even downright skeptical and distrustful, of templates you've found somewhere on the Internet!)

Finally, create truncated citation call-outs with `\citet` and `\citep`, and create non-truncated citation call-outs with `\citet*` and `\citep*`.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@article{abc, 
      author  = "Anne Author and Bertha Buthor and 
                 Carla Cuthor", 
      title   = "Thoughts", 
      journal = "Circularity Today",
      year    = 3001,
      volume  = 1,
      number  = 2,
      pages   = "3-4",
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[square, authoryear]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat} % or some other suitable bib style
                             % note that 'apalike* is *not* suitable

\begin{document}
\noindent
\cite{abc}; \citet*{abc}; \citep{abc}; \citep*{abc}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is great, thanks. What is wrong with apalike, by the way? What determines which bib styles are appropriate for which packages / configs?

Comment: @user1018464 - `apalike` is one of the original BibTeX style files, and it hasn't really been updated meaningfully since about 1984. `apalike` was written long before the `natbib` package was created, and it formats the labels of bib entries in a peculiar way that simply isnt't flexible enough to allow `\citet*` and `\citep*` to operate as expected. In general, if a bibliography style file was created with the `makebst` utility (check the bst file's header information to verify), it's probably flexible enough to let `\citet*` and `\citep*` operate properly.